# How to insert row in data grid in VB6

Tags: vb6, datagrid

I just need the code to add a row with text per column to a data grid.
It can be for DBGrid/DataGrid I won't mind but I'm struggling to find how to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a long while since I used dbgrid, but if I recall correctly, you can't add arbitrary text. The dbgrid control is bound to a recordset.

see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231246%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

and/or

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149092

Comment: Yes, the data grid controls are meant for use with data binding rather than procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
grid.textmatrix(grid_col,grid_row) = "sample text"
```